# How can I drag-and-drop virtual files that are created after the drop, from a UWP app?

Tags: c#, uwp, drag-and-drop

I'm writing a UWP app that supports dragging virtual files to the Windows Shell. The files are sometimes big. So I don't want to start downloading and processing the content until the file is dropped (or pasted). Legacy desktop apps could do this by implementing `CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR` and `CFSTR_FILECONTENTS` clipboard formats. Is there any way to get similar functionality from a UWP app?

**What I've Tried**

I know that UWP has a nifty way to drag-and-drop files to the shell, but I can't find a way to delay file creation until the drop. In the example below, the delayed data provider gets called immediately when the file drags over Windows Explorer.

```
private void GridView_DragItemsStarting(object s, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Data.SetDataProvider(StandardDataFormats.StorageItems, async (DataProviderRequest request) =>
    {
        //This code runs immediately when file gets dragged over the Windows shell.
    });
}
```

I have also experimented with `StorageFile.ReplaceWithStreamedFileAsync()` but again, the whole file is requested immediately before the file is dropped. Is there a way to delay the data request until after the file is dropped?

This problem is even worse when I try to copy a virtual file to the clipboard. The file data is immediately requested.

Comment: CoreDragOperation.DragUIContentMode is all you got.  Did you try setting it to Defer?

Comment: That sounds promising. Can you tell me how to modify the CoreDragOperation from within my GridView_DragItemsStarting function?

Comment: What's the result if you manually drag it to a win32 app using the way you mentioned?

Comment: I've only tried explorer.exe (which is a win32 app). As soon as I drag over explorer.exe, the full file data is requested, as I described.

Comment: @j_6582 Actually I've reproduced this issue. And after the discussion from the internal channel. What I want to share is that we’re hitting a design limitation here (drag&drop of streamed files to File explorer).